# Can't ping my external CGNAT IP address from external network

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat

I'm new to networking and I'm trying to scan my external IP from an external network.

I first tried finding my public IP from whatismyIP.com. The IP address on that site was different from the external IP address on my home router so I assumed my network used a Carrier Grade NAT device.

I tried scanning the IP I got from whatismyIP.com using nmap and also tried pinging it. I was able to do so inside my router's network, but not when I was outside it. I was wondering if anyone could explain why I couldn't ping or scan the address from whatismyIP.com outside my network. Does it have something to do with the CGNAT.

Comment: The downvotes will be for just idly copy/pasting the entire question including the close reason. Telling us what IP addresses you *did* see would make answers more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

"Your" CGNAT IP address is not really yours; it belongs to the NAT gateway. Depending on the ISP's setup, it might not always be pingable:

1. The ISP might have simply blocked ping requests on the gateway, as some admins do. (Much like Windows blocks ping requests; it's just a firewall rule.) If the address is pingable from inside but not outside, that's the most likely explanation.
2. The address might not be *assigned to* the gateway at all, only routed towards it. This makes no difference to packets that the gateway does translate, but when a new packet comes in that doesn't match an existing translation, it *could* literally go nowhere instead of being accepted by the router itself.